# Cannot change country in Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-account, google-play-store

I want to change my country in Gmail. I originally set up my Gmail in Spain but moved back to the UK. It is showing both my Gmail and Play Store as Spain.

I used the following advice:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7431675?hl=en&authuser=3#zippy=%2Ci-dont-see-the-option-to-add-a-country

I didn't get an option to change the country. None of the following apply:

You may not see this option if:

- You've changed your country within the last year -  **I haven't**
- You aren’t currently in a new country. This is based on your IP address - **definitely in the UK**
- You’re part of a Google Play Family Library - **Haven't set one up**

How else can I change the country?

Comment: Can you tell please - did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think that help is incorrect.

1. Click on the grid pattern and select Account
2. Select Payments and Subscriptions
3. Click on Manage Payment Methods
4. Select **Addresses** tab
5. You may have to enter a payment method as well (I don't remember, but I do have different cards assigned to each account)

It is a nuisance that you can't change it often.  I ended up having 5 accounts for different countries that I need it for.  All are registered on my mobile and I simply change the account as necessary.

Comment: Thanks Rohit,   I have set the profile and added a payment method all for the UK as you have directed.  When I try to buy extra storage it is still trying to charge me in Euros.  On the play store, under settings/general/account and device preferences the country is still Spain, and I can't change from Spain to UK.